Normal force change due to bending moment
If a column is applied a compression force from top and it is fixed from bottom. And I apply a shear force on its top that produces a bending moment in CW or CCW direction. Can I find the change in compression force when column is bent in any section along the column axis. Or at the top and the bottom sections, can I find the change in compression force due to that bending?
Specifically, this refers to the model of a preloaded bolt subjected to transverse sinusoidal vibration. Nassar and Housari have measured this force in equations 4c and 5 of the paper "Housari, Basil A., and Sayed A. Nassar. "Effect of thread and bearing friction coefficients on the vibration-induced loosening of threaded fasteners." (2007): 484-494".
They took the change in axial force as:
$$ F = P \times r_t \times d \phi $$
Where
$P$ is the thread contact force per unit length in the circumferential
direction, $r_t$ is the mean thread radius and $d \phi$ is the angle of one sector out of the whole circle.
Then they multiply by $r_t \times cos(\phi)$ to get the bending moment. $\phi$ is the angle from 1st sector to the sector under observation.
If anyone could explain me I would be very greatful. Thank you for your response in advance.
Regards
